# Why is gradle-jaxb-plugin catenating namespace URL with file spec?

Tags: gradle, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

Trying to move from maven-jaxb2-plugin to gradle-jaxb-plugin.

Here is my script:

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'

dependencies {
  jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
  jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11'
  jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11'
}

jaxb {
  xsdDir = "/commons/schemas/widgets/src/main/resources/v1"
}
```

`gradle clean xjc` 
 then  results in:

```
Execution failed for task ':commons:schemas:widgets:xsd-dependency-tree'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /development/project/commons/schemas/widgets/src/main/resources/v1/http:/ourjoint.com/schema/commons/v1 (No such file or directory)
```

Now then.... any ideas why it wants to catenate the namespace URL onto this file location like that?

```
ls /development/project/commons/schemas/widgets/src/main/resources/v1/
```

shows that this IS where the XSD's are, so it would be correct except for that namespace address that somehow got appended to it.

Comment: No idea, but all the examples have `xsdDir` with no `/` prefix

Comment: Actually, it sounds like this issue.  https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/13

Comment: Yup. It looks A LOT like that. :-/